# How to align multiple row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

## Scenario

There is a column.

There are 4 children in this colum

The first 2 are Rows (R1 and R2)

The 3rd is a Divider

The last is a Row (R3)

Each of the Row contains a text that should expand all available space in the left and a sub-rows that contains 3 children each of dynamic width. These 3 children should align (on the vertical axis) with the other children in R1, R2 and R3.

## Problem

The children of the sub-rows do not align as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

[image]

## Question

How to make the children of the sub-rows in R1, R2, R3 align?

The longest dynamic child should dictate the width

## Reproducible code: (Hint just copy-paste on dartpad.dev  and hit run)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children:[
           Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Text('Main Balance')),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text('350 Rs'),
                  Padding(
                    child: Text('->'),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  ),
                  Text('35000 USD'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),

          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Text('Credit Balance')),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text('350 Rs'),
                  Padding(
                    child: Text('->'),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  ),
                  Text('35 USD'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Divider(),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Text('Total')),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text('350 Rs'),
                  Padding(
                    child: Text('->'),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  ),
                  Text('35000000 USD'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

## Attempt

I attempted to use 3 Columns instead of one Row, but then I faced another issue, WHERE DO I PUT THE DIVIDER ?

Comment: Why not use the table, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html

Comment: @faroukosama already tried that too, table forces all the width to be the same. So the text on the left wont expand all available space

Answer (score 4):

try this:

use the `Table` Widget, and you can customize as you wish

```
Table(
        columnWidths: {2: FlexColumnWidth(0.2)},
        children: [
          TableRow(children: [
            Text('Main Balance'),
            Text('350 Rs'),
            Text('->'),
            Text('35000 USD'),
          ]),
          TableRow(children: [
            Text('Credit Balance'),
            Text('350 Rs'),
            Text('->'),
            Text('35 USD'),
          ]),
          TableRow(children: [
            Divider(),
            Divider(),
            Divider(),
            Divider(),
          ]),
          TableRow(children: [
            Text('Total'),
            Text('350 Rs'),
            Text('->'),
            Text('35000000 USD'),
          ]),
        ],
      ),
```

the result code is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use DataTable widget to show your data

[image]

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: DataTable(
    columns: [
      DataColumn(label: Text('Explain')),
      DataColumn(label: Text('Column 1')),
      DataColumn(label: Text('Column 2')),
    ],
    rows: [
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text('Main Balance')),
        DataCell(Text('350 Rs')),
        DataCell(Text('35000 USD')),
      ]),
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text('Credit Balance')),
        DataCell(Text('350 Rs')),
        DataCell(Text('35 USD')),
      ]),
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text('Total')),
        DataCell(Text('350 Rs')),
        DataCell(Text('35000000 USD')),
      ]),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text('Main Balance')),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('350 Rs'),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    child: Text('->'),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('35000 USD', textAlign: TextAlign.end),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text('Credit Balance')),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('350 Rs'),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    child: Text('->'),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('35 USD', textAlign: TextAlign.end),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Divider(),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text('Total')),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('350 Rs'),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    child: Text('->'),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('35000000 USD', textAlign: TextAlign.end),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```